# What's the best way to clear cached JSON responses from a third-party API?

Tags: plugin-development, cache

I'm building a plugin to browse store orders via a third-party API. I make various requests to URLs that can include query parameters:

- `/customers`
- `/orders/e8b48e72-9c7f-4d6f-91aa-2f7238bdf936`
- `/orders?offset=0&limit=250&from=2014-05-26T22%3A58%3A38%2B00%3A00&to=2014-06-26T22%3A58%3A38%2B00%3A00`

I've just started using Guzzle and more importantly `craft()->fileCache` to keep results around for a few minutes and speed up browsing. I use the query URI as the key for the cache:

```
 craft()->fileCache->set($query, $response->getBody(true), 600); // store result for 10 minutes
```

A web hook gets hit with every new order that comes in, making it an ideal time to clear out these caches I've set—but I have no idea *how*.

Is there any way I can tag this plugin's caches or somehow clear out only those I've made, rather than get overzealous with `craft()->fileCache->flushValues()`?

Comment: I know you're out there, @VictorIn.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [delete a cache](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CCache#delete-detail) as follows:

```
craft()->fileCache->delete($key);
```

So instead of caching individual keys, you could perhaps cache an array of keys and delete the entire array when you want to clear out your keys.

Comment: Thanks Ben! An array of keys seems to make way more sense.

Comment: glad you agree!

Comment: You've given me the concept of a multi-dimensional cache *and* Guzzle this week. I can't even imagine what next week has in store.

Comment: Has `craft()->fileCache` has been updated to just `craft()->cache`?

Comment: No, it is one of the available caching methods: http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/etc/cache/FileCache